# Need a seperate layout for single product of a category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a single product page based on category.

I created a template and used the below function which successfully calls the template

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_single_product_template_include', 50, 1 );
function custom_single_product_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( is_singular('product') && (has_term( 'home-show', 'product_cat')) ) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-56772.php';
    } 
    return $template;
}
```

Now how to change the layout of the page. So in general in single product page we

```
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
```

But this calls the layout of old page only.

So I have replicated single-product folder with name "single-product-56772" and changed template call to

```
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-56772' ); ?>
```

But this do not help. Nothing gets loaded. Can some one help me figure out where I am going wrong so I cn load a new layout for that particular category.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just your working filter, you can directly change your new template file `single-product-56772.php` without calling any other file.

If you want to call the `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-56772' );` from `single-product-56772.php` then you have to create that file in your woocommerce folder and name it `content-single-product-56772.php`.

Your files structure should look like this:

```
woocommerce
  |- single-product-56772.php
  |- content-single-product-56772.php
```

Comment: Perfect worked like a charm .  But can I ask you how can we over write inner template that are in single-product folder of woocommerce.

Likewise said above created a folder single-product-56772 and added files "product-image.php" "related" "tabs" etc bit single-product files are being called.

Comment: In your theme file add a folder woocommerce and in that file add the single-product folder. In there just add the files you want to override ('product-image.php' etc)

Comment: Correct but this over rides all the products . I want to over ride only this category .